# Is there anyway to condense my current code so that it isn't one long line (without making separate lines)

Tags: java, println

I'm currently working on a project for a Java class where we have to print out our schedule. I've got my code to look the way I want the final code to be. We can only use one System.out.print() This is so we can practice using escape sequences. However, my teacher said that I need to condense my line of code and find a way to not make it dragged on. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my current code:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Period\t\t\t\tClass\t\t\t\t\tComment\n1\t\t\t\t\tPrecalculus\t\t\t\tBoring\n2\t\t\t\t\tJava\t\t\t\t\tCool\n3\t\t\t\t\tHonors Chinese\t\t\tInteresting\n4\t\t\t\t\tGym\t\t\t\t\t\tIrrelevant\n5\t\t\t\t\tEnglish\t\t\t\t\tEasy\n6\t\t\t\t\tAP World\t\t\t\tHard\n7\t\t\t\t\tAP Physics\t\t\t\tAlso Hard\n8\t\t\t\t\tVoices\t\t\t\t\tExciting");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your requirements are not really clear.

Answer (score 1):

1. It is better to represent the data as an object(of a class).
2. The object can be printed as per the need

The following code will

1. Define a new class `Schedule` to represent the record
2. Schedule can override `toString` method to print its internal state
3. The `toString` can use a `Formatter` if needed
4. Create multiple `Schedule` objects and print them using the `toString`
5. Print the column before printing the actual objects (this is where my implementation is slightly offtrack)

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ScheduleFormatter {

    static class Schedule {
        public static final String FORMAT = "%-15s %-20s %s";
        private final int period;
        private final String className;
        private final String comment;

        public Schedule(int period, String className, String comment) {
            this.period = period;
            this.className = className;
            this.comment = comment;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(FORMAT, this.period, this.className, this.comment);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Schedule> schedules = new ArrayList<>();
        schedules.add(new Schedule(1, "Precalculus", "Boring"));
        schedules.add(new Schedule(2, "Java", "Cool"));
        System.out.println(String.format(Schedule.FORMAT, "Period", "Class", "Comment"));
        schedules.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Even the List can be contained in another object and that container object can override the `toString`.

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ScheduleFormatter {

    static class Schedule {
        public static final String FORMAT = "%-15s %-20s %s\n";
        private final int period;
        private final String className;
        private final String comment;

        public Schedule(int period, String className, String comment) {
            this.period = period;
            this.className = className;
            this.comment = comment;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(FORMAT, this.period, this.className, this.comment);
        }
    }

    static class Schedules {
        private String[] headers;
        private List<Schedule> schedules;

        Schedules(String[] headers) {
            this.headers = headers;
            this.schedules = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        public void add(Schedule schedule) {
            this.schedules.add(schedule);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.append(String.format(Schedule.FORMAT, headers));
            schedules.forEach(builder::append);
            return builder.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Schedules schedules = new Schedules(new String[] {"Period", "Class", "Comment"});
        schedules.add(new Schedule(1, "Precalculus", "Boring"));
        schedules.add(new Schedule(2, "Java", "Cool"));
        System.out.println(schedules);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Text blocks

In Java 15 and later, you can use [text blocks](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378) to make this code somewhat more readable.

To quote that JEP 378:

> The escape sequences \b (backspace), \t (tab) and \s (space) are not interpreted by the algorithm; escape processing happens later.

```java
System.out.println(
        """
        Period\t\t\t\tClass\t\t\t\t\tComment
        1\t\t\t\t\tPrecalculus\t\t\t\tBoring
        2\t\t\t\t\tJava\t\t\t\t\tCool
        3\t\t\t\t\tHonors Chinese\t\t\tInteresting
        4\t\t\t\t\tGym\t\t\t\t\t\tIrrelevant
        5\t\t\t\t\tEnglish\t\t\t\t\tEasy
        6\t\t\t\t\tAP World\t\t\t\tHard
        7\t\t\t\t\tAP Physics\t\t\t\tAlso Hard
        8\t\t\t\t\tVoices\t\t\t\t\tExciting
        """
);
```

When run.

```
Period              Class                   Comment
1                   Precalculus             Boring
2                   Java                    Cool
3                   Honors Chinese          Interesting
4                   Gym                     Irrelevant
5                   English                 Easy
6                   AP World                Hard
7                   AP Physics              Also Hard
8                   Voices                  Exciting
```